# Android parse JSON data into a HashTable?

Tags: android

[image]

I get data from a web service as JSON data. The displayed data is shown in the image: it's basically a class called Questionnaire which has two properties which are QuestionnaireId and QuestionnaireName. So the web service method I call returns a collections of this class Questionnaire.

I am trying to parse this data to an HashTable which I am not able to. Kindly help me get this data parsed into a `Hashtable<QuestionnaireId,QuestionnaireName>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want something along the lines of this:

```
Hashtable<Integer,String> table = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();

/* ... */

JsonObject root = new JsonObject(json_string);
JsonArray questions = root.getJsonArray("d");
for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
    JsonObject question = questions.getJsonObject(i);
    int id = question.optInt("QuestionnaireId", -1);
    String name = question.optString("QuestionnaireName");
    table.put(id, name);
}
```

(Roughly...)

Answer (score 3):

i parse some json string with this method, hope helps you

```
public static Vector<MyObject> getImagesFromJson(String jos){
        Vector<MyObject> images = null;
        try{

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jos);

            JSONArray array = jo.getJSONArray("images");
            if(array != null && array.length() > 0){
                images = new Vector<MyObject>();
            }
            for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
                MyObject object = new MyObject();
                object.setEpigrafe( array.getJSONObject( i ).get( "epigrafe" ).toString() );
                object.setId( array.getJSONObject( i ).getInt( "id" ) );
                object.setUrl( array.getJSONObject( i ).get( "url" ).toString() );
                images.add(object);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            images = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return images;
    }

where MyObjects is defined as:

    private int id;
    private String url;
    private String epigrafe;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily ask google: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to not just stuff it into a Map but to map the data to POJOs and then fill a List with that POJOs.

Define your POJO like this.

```
public class Questionnaire {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Questionnaire() {
        setId(0);
        setName(null);
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Create a List of `Questionnaire` objects.

Now create a new `Questionnaire` object every time you need one and map the parsed data to to it using the setters.

Once you are done with one `Questionnaire` object add it to the List.